# Excel VBA: How To Remove Duplicate Values From Table?

Tags: vba, excel

Thoroughly searched StackOverflow and Google but didn't find answer to this.

Trying to remove duplicate values from a **table** in Excel (not just spreadsheet)

Current code:

```
Sub RemoveDuplicates()
ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table1").ListColumns(1).DataBodyRange.RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlYes
End Sub
```

**Issue:**

This code requires the data in EVERY column of the table to be identical before it's considered duplicate. (Discovered this through testing).

**Goal:**

Check for duplicate values only in column 1 of the table then, when duplicates are found, remove the entire row. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 3):

Try the code below:

```
Option Explicit

Sub RemoveDuplicates()

Dim TblRng As Range

Set TblRng = ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table1").Range        
TblRng.RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlYes

End Sub
```

Comment: Looks like this yields the same result as the original code. Only erases the duplicate row if data in every column match (rather than just matching column 1 data)

Answer (score 1):

Or

```
Option Explicit

Sub RemoveDuplicates()
   ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table1").DataBodyRange.RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlNo
End Sub
```

Comment: @Jeeped Thank you. And I will need to spend some time working through your answer to that other question regarding Large!

Comment: Tested. This also yields the same result as the original code. Only erases the duplicate row if data in every column match (rather than just matching column 1 data)

Comment: Can you show a screenshot of the table and supply some data? It worked for me in the tests I ran. From your solution this sounds suspiciously [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

Answer (score 1):

Found solution! Actually, it's a bit of a workaround. I researched 20 different code options for ".RemoveDuplicates" and had zero success with any of them. Here's the code

```
Sub sbFindDuplicatesInColumn2()
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim matchFoundIndex As Long
    Dim iCntr As Long
    lastRow = Range("A65000").End(xlUp).Row

For iCntr = 1 To lastRow
  If Cells(iCntr, 1) <> "" Then
    matchFoundIndex = WorksheetFunction.Match(Cells(iCntr, 1), Range("A1:A" & lastRow), 0)
    If iCntr <> matchFoundIndex Then
            Cells(iCntr, 2).EntireRow.Delete xlShiftUp
            'Line below is because when a row is deleted the row numbers change so the next row is skipped via the counter unless we have the line below
            iCntr = iCntr - 1
   End If
  End If
Next

End Sub
```

**Notes on the code:**

- Works whether sheet has a table or not
- Keeps first instance of duplicate and removes the rest (make sure your table is first sorted properly!)
- Checks for duplicates only in the desired column yet will delete the entire row

Took so much time for something so simple. I hope this will help others!

Answer (score 0):

Try,

```
ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table1").Range.RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlYes
```

[image]

Comment: Tested and also same result as the original code. Only erases the duplicate row if data in every column match (rather than just matching column 1 data)

Comment: Well it certainly doesn't do that for me. Tested above and working as required.

Answer (score 0):

I have had a similar problem. In the Microsoft Docs the Columns:= parameter is defined as array. After changing the parameter in my code to Columns:=Array(1,1) the result was as expected. My code now is:

```
RefDest.DataBodyRange.RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1, 1), Header:=xlNo
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your table is named "Data", and the column to look at is "NumCode", this code works and is easy:

```
    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Raw Data").ListObjects("Data")
        .Range.RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(.ListColumns("NumCode").Index), Header:=xlYes
    End With
```

With this, it doesn't matter where the column is in the table and if it gets moved (adding or removing other columns), it doesn't matter.

Answer (score 0):

I just record a macro in excel and remove the duplicates in my table in one column manualy trough the "Data Tools" option in the toolbar, and that was the result, let me know if it work for you all too :)

```
Sub RemoveDuplicates()
  ActiveSheet.Range("TbIstFiles5[#All]").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=12, _
  Header :=xlYes
End Sub
```