# VBA delete duplicates

Tags: vba, duplicates

I've been searching for a VBA macro to look for duplicates and delete the rows where the duplicates are.

```
Dim Plage As Range
Dim Cel As Range
With Workbooks(Fichier).Worksheets("Facture")
'from A27 to A39
   Set Plage = .Range(.Cells(27, 1), .Cells(39, 1).End(xlUp))
End With
For Each Cel In Plage
    If Application.CountIf(Plage, Cel.Value) > 1 Then
        MsgBox "cel.row : " & Cel.Row
        If Cel.Row = 27 Or Cel.Row = 29 Or Cel.Row = 31 Or Cel.Row = 33 Or Cel.Row = 35 Or Cel.Row = 
        37 Or Cel.Row = 39 Then
            MsgBox "duplicate found"
            Cel.Interior.ColorIndex = 3
        Else ' duplicate on date => skip it
            MsgBox "duplicate date"
        End If
    End If
Next Cel
```

My goal is to keep one duplicates, and not to delete them all, and i'm a bit lost there :/
(i'll use Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp)

So this is the result (i keep only odd rows as duplicates).

EDIT : [This what i have right now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0EXih.png)

[This what RemoveDuplicate gives me](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LdMxI.png)

EDIT2 : adding `Workbooks(Fichier).Worksheets("Facture").Range("A" & Cel.Row & ":A" & Cel.Row + 1 & "").EntireRow.Select` instead of coloring the cell works fine.

Now i need to get the value `Range("A" & Cel.Row + 1 & "").Value` previously deleted and add it to my kept cell like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KjWqn.png)

But i don't know how to keep the position of the non duplicate cell adress

Comment: why not use [Range.RemoveDuplicates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.removeduplicates)  It will keep the first instance and remove all others.

Comment: Keep one duplicate? You want to have one duplicate but not more?

Comment: RemoveDuplicate will only remove them, i need to delete the rows

Comment: i want only 1 of each

Comment: If you tried @ScottCraner's advice you would achieve what you want.

Comment: @Robin you would just reference the whole range of columns and then indicate on which of those columns you want to look for duplicates.

Comment: Range.RemoveDuplicates is only deleting the cell itself, not the complete rows. It's not what i'm looking for

Comment: I will only have duplicate in column A, from A26 et A39, whenever i found 1 duplicate (only on odd rows numbers) i will delete 2 rows for this duplicate (row and row+1)

Answer (score 0):

The below code will [remove duplicate rows if you convert your data into an Excel Table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49953130/excel-vba-how-to-remove-duplicate-values-from-table).

```
Option Explicit
Sub RemoveDuplicates()
Dim TblRng As Range
Set TblRng = ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table1").Range
TblRng.RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlYes
End Sub
```

Comment: Thx but it's only removing it, not deleting the rows

Answer (score 0):

Pretty much found the solution, it works ... fine for now

Thx for help :)